# Permanent loss of voting corrected

Tags: support, bug, reputation, upvotes, serial-voting

In the wee hours of the morning (UTC time), I received six upvotes in quick succession on six different questions.  These are old questions, so this is suspiciously like serial upvoting (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=reputation)).

Three hours later, 60 points were removed for serial upvoting.  I assume it was these 6 upvotes (I have not noted other suspicious activity in the past few days).

I have no problem with the votes being reversed.  However, these reversed votes still seem to account toward the 200 points per day limit on upvotes.  So, today the limit is reached at 140 points.  Additional upvotes beyond 14 do not count.

The question is:  Why are reversed serial upvotes still counted toward the daily maximum?  If this is the case, it seems like a bug.  If there is merely a delay in rectifying this, then I can delete this question.

While I'm asking a question on this topic, why don't I see the acknowledgment that a particular upvote was removed?

Comment: @honk . . . Funny.  First, in my searches, I did not see that question.  Second, I'm surprised that if the OP decides to close something as a duplicate, it does not take effect immediately.

Comment: @Gordon did your VTC, or did you click 'this answers my question' in the banner at the top? VTC wont do it, but the other will.